# Easiest way t convert a large XML file to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I have a 63MB XML file which is basically a list of chess players, it looks like this:

```
<playerslist>
   <player>
       <fideid></fideid>
       <name></name>
       <country></country>
       <sex></sex>
       <title></title>
       <rating></rating>
   </player>
   <player>
      ...
   </player>
</playerslist>
```

I want to use this data on a website and be able to do searches on it, so having it as a table in a mySQL database would be the most convenient thing for me. 
So, what would be the easiest way to convert this XML file to a mySQL database?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [load-xml](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html) it would be something like this (considering columns are named exactly as the tags)

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/players.xml'
INTO TABLE players
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<player>';
```

There is another potential approach that may work if the tags don't match columns:

```
LOAD XML INFILE '/path/to/players.xml'
INTO TABLE players (@fide_id, @name, @country, @sex, @title, @rating)
SET fide_id = @fide_id, name = @name, country = @country, sex = @sex, title = @title, rating = @rating
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<player>'
```

Comment: Just tried the first one out, it's taking pretty long... Maybe the XML is too large for that to work.

Comment: How big is the XML file?

Comment: 63MB, about 3 million lines in the XML

Comment: Hmm. How long did you let it sit? Did it insert any rows? You can do a `SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM Table;` before and after to see. Otherwise, you might be better off using something like Ruby to digest the data.